# USB devices missing from /proc/acpi/wakeup

Tags: ubuntu, usb, suspend, acpi, hid

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 (specifically the Kodibuntu port) on a Gibabyte NUC like mini pc. My kernel version is 3.13.0-55-generic.

I'm having trouble enabling wake-up from suspend via my usb remote keyboard. I have no USB entries in /proc/acpi/wakeup.

This is my current configuration:

```
root@romulus:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:1078 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 400c:107a
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3410 IMC Networks
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My keyboard is the 400c:107a device running un bus 1 device 4.

```
root@romulus:~# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-4/power/wakeup
enabled
```

Yet, even after trying to add USB1 to acpi wakeup i still can't see the USB devices in /proc/acpi/wakeup:

```
root@romulus:~# echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
root@romulus:~# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
XHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PWRB      S0    *enabled
root@romulus:~#
```

Can someone explain me why there are no USB devices here? I've searched the interwebs for answers but most people solve the problem after echoing the usb device to /proc/acpi/wakeup of ater setting the power/wakeup file to enabled for the specific device.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Have you ever found this out? I have the opposite problem preventing my mouse to wake the computer up ...

Comment: Never. I sold the mini PC because of this. And replaced with with an android based one.

Comment: I'm also having this issue where the USB is missing. Can't seem to spot anything on the net. I've tried this to no avail https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#Waking_from_suspend_with_USB_device -- linking in case someone else has luck. Funny thing is, if I `echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup` then it wakes up immediately after going to suspend even with no USB devices attached.